# Ошибка [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) в nginx

Tags: nginx, google-cloud

Не установлен Apache, так и не могу понять кто занял порт 8080, да и проверял командой sudo lsof -i :8080:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там только сам nginx

Файл конфигурации nginx default:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080 ipv6only=on;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Эм, а при чём тут вообще 8080? nginx же настроен на порт 80, занят порт 80, вот и проверяйте порт 80

Comment: Покажите вывод `sudo netstat -pan | grep ":8080"`

Comment: @andreymal, уже сделал правку в вопросе, порт выставил 8080, тоже самое

Comment: И ещё покажите, что в директории `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` лежит. Может у вас там больше 1 конфиг файла.

Comment: @Suvitruf tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11914/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11914/nginx -g daem

Comment: @Suvitruf, только один default лежит

Comment: А какую команду вы выполняете?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, команду для чего?

Comment: После которой вы получаете эту ошибку